# The regular expression error is malformed

Tags: regex, xml

I have error^

```
The regular expression '.+@^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.^[A-Za-z]{2,4}' is malformed: '-' is an invalid character range. Write '\-'
```

How can I fix it

Comment: Where and how is the regex used? Is it something that `LC_ALL=C` can fix? What are those `^` doing in the pattern?

Comment: You've tagged the question "xml" - is that relevant? The key thing is, different regex dialects vary, and you need to tell us which one you are using. But since the error message tells you how to fix the problem, why don't you do what it suggests?

Comment: looks like you have to escape that "-" in your "[...]"

Comment: Could someone tell me in which language this regex makes sense? With the `^` there

Comment: Is that used in ElasticSearch? If yes, then the `-` must be escaped at the end of the character class. But the multiple `^` symbols inside still do not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, it means that you must escape the character `'-'` by writing `'\-'` within the regular expression, when it's not used as a range indicator.

Try to change:

```
'.+@^[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.^[A-Za-z]{2,4}'
```

by

```
'.+@^[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.^[A-Za-z]{2,4}'
```

As @Fallenhero stated. The `'^'` seem also to be misplaced somehow.

Comment: not true. In most languages the `.` automatically gets escaped in `[]`